# Server: access console output from other TTY/terminal

Tags: command-line, server

I administer a server via SSH login from different machines. I started a task in a ssh terminal on client1. Then I went to another building and logged in with the same user in another SSH session to that server.

From client2 Is there a way I can see the console output of the session started in client1?

Comment: Use a terminal multiplexer, such as [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)

Comment: @user4556274 Why not write an answer that explains how to install and utilize `tmux` for this purpose.

Comment: @user4556274  I would love to see how this is used, if you could please add an answer

Comment: @user4556274 Thanks for the link. I have been following the link since you set it, but still its not clear to me what a terminal mux exactly is and how its used. I just found 2 websites with some examples so I can see what is does and how its employed.However, it seems to me that tmux is not a way to access the output that I had just started, I should have started under tmux in the first place, correct? If so, it would be interesting to know if there is a common log file I could manually access as admin or similar.

Comment: @CatMan yes, tmux is not a solution for the situation you are in; it is a tool to use in future to avoid that situation.  Generally, output from another tty is not available unless you have set up something in advance, whether a multiplexer (tmux, screen), or a means of "logging" the output (script).

Comment: @user4556274 thanks, I saw you comment after writing the answer. Hopefully its reflecting that view. Its great to have that confirmation in the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [user4556274](https://askubuntu.com/users/570428/user4556274) for the link to tmux,

for all like me who never heard of tmux and the concept of terminal multiplexing.

Is a bit like a window manager for the console. Typical use case it to start working from one place on a remote machine, then move(fly) to another place and reconnect from there to exactly pick up your session from before. So it just covers my use case. 
However, in order to work you need to start tmux **before** you start doing stuff in your session. So if you forget, its no help to get back to the other session.

However, from what I read in the net it seems most people with those kind of use cases seem to get a hang of using tmux as a default.

Note: i found most google results more confusing than helpful. They lost me right away. The one that got me the very brief top-top-top-level overview was this [one](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tmux/#gs.w_FA8bs), maybe its also helpful for others.